# Either proactive or proactively?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> 1.The private sector is responding as well, sometimes **proactive** and sometimes concurrent with government mandates.
>
> 2.The private sector is responding as well, sometimes **proactively** and sometimes concurrent with government mandates.

I think both of the above sentences are grammatical.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost a trick question because *neither* sentence in the question is grammatical.

The verb *responding* requires modification by adverbs, not adjectives.

The sentence can be simplified like this:

> ✘ The private sector is **responding** ***proactive***.
>   ✔ The private sector is **responding** ***proactively***.
>
> ✘ The private sector is **responding** ***concurrent***.
>   ✔ The private sector is **responding** ***concurrently***.

There is only a single correct sentence, and it doesn't appear in the question:

> The private sector is **responding** as well, sometimes ***proactively*** and sometimes ***concurrently*** with government mandates.